# SQL - Get the values of another column for values in a given column

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am working with a large data table. I want to check the individual items with their destination and the count of destinations if there are more than 1 destination for a given item.

So in the below image, in my result, I should not get Items Grapes and Rice since there is only one destination for them. I want to filter by the destination as well. I need to remove the items which are going to the same destination. So here, only Apple and their respective destinations are the ones I need. Orange should be removed because its going to the same destination.

The query I have written is below. However it does not serve the purpose.This does not filter out same destinations. Any help please ?

```
select Item,
listagg(Destination, ',') within group (order by Destination) as Destination
from ProductsTable
group by Item
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data as
(
  select 'Apple' as item, 'Rome' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Apple' as item, 'Barcelona' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Apple' as item, 'Moscow' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Apple' as item, 'Paris' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Apple' as item, 'London' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Orange' as item, 'Cairo' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Orange' as item, 'Cairo' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Orange' as item, 'Cairo' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Grapes' as item, 'Berlin' as destination from dual union all
  select 'Rice' as item, 'Manila' as destination from dual
)
select Item,
listagg(Destination, ',') within group (order by Destination) as Destination
from data
group by Item having count(distinct destination) > 1;

ITEM   DESTINATION                                       
------ --------------------------------------------------
Apple  Barcelona,London,Moscow,Paris,Rome
```

Comment: Hi Balazs, thanks for the answer.Answer works but gives ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long".

However I resolved it using wm_concat like this.select Item, wm_concat(distinct Destination) col2_list 
from ProductsTable
group by Item
having count(distinct Destination) > 1; 

Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: @Ran_Macavity `wm_concat` was never documented and it was removed from newer releases.